# Android : intent action mail received

Tags: android, email, android-intent, action

On Android, I try to intercept mails received to do some stuff in my app.

To do it, I use intent in my app manifest :

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.email.intent.action.EMAIL_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="email" />
            <data android:host="messages" />
        </intent-filter>
```

It works fine when I use K9 mail client.

But it doesn't work with gmail app, or with native mail app.

I think I miss the correct intent action, have you got it ?

Thanks in advance !